# Odoo 12 report sample

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I am trying to make a report but without using `external_layout` or `internal_layout` because they have headers in them. I wanted to have my own header and footer.

I have tried using `minimal_layout` because it seems it is the less busy layout compared to other layouts.

But I kept having error `body_parent = root.xpath('//main')[0] IndexError: list index out of range - - -`

Here is my code

```
<template id="applicant_contract_css">
    <t t-call="web._assets_helpers"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/fhid_recruitment/static/src/css/applicant-contract.css"/>
</template>

<template id="minimal_layout" inherit_id="web.minimal_layout">
    <xpath expr="//head" position="inside">
        <t t-call-assets="fhid_recruitment.applicant_contract_css"/>
    </xpath>
</template>

<template id="applicant_contract_offering">
    <t t-call="web.minimal_layout">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="header">
                My Header
            </div>
            <div class="article">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                My footer
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

How do I use `minimal layout`? or is there another layout should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want create a template report you need to at least call, `"web.html_container"` witch call `"web.report_layout"` witch define `Minal Report layout` .

all `css` file for report template should be add to `report_assets_common` template:

```xml
<template id="assets_common" name="a proper name for your template purpuse" inherit_id="web.report_assets_common">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/fhid_recruitment/static/src/css/applicant-contract.css"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

It's better to extract your header and footer to template so you use them in multiple report, like the `external_layout`, you can take a look at the `external_layout_standard` to get the basic Idea.

```xml
<template id="external_layout">
    <div class="header">
        My Header
    </div>
    <!-- everything inside t-call="fhid_recruitment.external_layout" will be rendered here -->
    <t t-raw="0" />

    <div class="footer">
        My footer
    </div>
</template>
```

In the template just call your custom external layout here:

```xml
<template id="applicant_contract_offering">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <!-- because it's defined in this module "fhid_recruitment" -->
        <t t-call="fhid_recruitment.external_layout">
           <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
               <div call="page">
                    <div class="article">
                        Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

One of the most import thing you need to know about template is the `<t t-raw="0" />`, if for example a template `x_template` have this when we call it like this:

```xml
<t t-call="x_template">
    any_content
</t>
```

what the `Qweb` engine will do is, replace  `<t t-raw="0" />` inside the `x_template` with  `any_content` when rendering the report.

To simplify things if you are going to use header and footer only for one template:

```xml
<template id="applicant_contract_offering">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="header">
                My Header
            </div>
            <div class="article">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                My footer
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit either `external_layout` or `internal_layout` and override the default behaviour with your custom code. And use it in your report.